# Edittext fields increases the size

Tags: android

In my android project, **main_activity.xml** is looks like:--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp" >


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/AppTheme"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_weight="75"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/AppTheme"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ok"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:maxWidth="48dp"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:minWidth="48dp"
            android:text="OK"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/AppTheme"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

this format is looks like:-- "**Mr.** **Annonomus** **button(ok)**"...`Mr. is an edittext field,Annonomus is also a edittext field and a ok button`..
It displays fine..But the problem is when I start writting into the second edittext field(means want to write "Annonomus" ) the edittext size is increasing and the ok button and another edittext field is decreasing in size..
How can i get that when I write any long name to edittext field the edittext field will remain same..

Comment: use editText width match_parent and a fixed height

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for your editText:

```
int px = editTextMessage.getWidth();
    editTextMessage.setMaxWidth(px);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and `android:layout_weight` in all the components inside the `linearlayout`.

You must change the `android:layout_width` to `match_parent` or a fixed value and remove the `android:layout_weight` of them. Don't forget to remove the latter, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Set android:maxLines="1" or android:singleLine="true" property in your EditText.